# Multiple criteria by OR in SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

In SQLAlchemy, when using `filter` to query, if I give multiple criteria separated by commas then the criteria are joined using `AND`.

How can I query by using multiple criteria by `OR` and the result must return all rows which fulfil any one of the criteria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `or_`:

```
from sqlalchemy import or_
query.filter(or_(Person.last_name == 'Hardy', Person.id_num == 620028467))
```

This `or_` clause is equivalent to the following `where` clause in SQL:

```
where Person.last_name = 'Hardy' or
      Person.id_num = 620028467
```

See the [docs here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#common-filter-operators).